# Deleted comment etiquette

Tags: discussion

Take the situation where somebody asks a simple offshoot question in a comment to an answer.  You give a quick answer to the question in a following comment, including an @ attribution.  The asker then deletes their comment containing the question.

Is it appropriate to leave your comment with the answer or should you delete it?

I have searched meta and not found this situation referenced.

Thanks,

Ced

Answer (score 2):

If you wrote the answer, try to integrate your reply to the answer.

See [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead):

> - Comments are second class citizens on the Stack Exchange network, not
>     designed to hold information for all eternity. They may get cleaned up
>     at any time. Generally, **truly important information should be
>     incorporated into an answer anyway** (either by posting a new answer, if
>     the information answers the question at least partially, or by editing
>     an existing answer, if the information is a minor complement or
>     clarification of that answer).

It's not a perfect system because users can in general only clean up (delete) their own comments, and what's left is orphaned replies to those comments.

It's also good to know that ([How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work))

> No reputation of any kind is earned or lost from comment votes.

So deleting one's "popular comment" should not be an issue if the information can be moved elsewhere.